# Unsubscribe link for WordPress subscriber

Tags: wordpress, email, unsubscribe, list-unsubscribe

My website having email subscription for subscribers. and it is done without any plugin. 
I am able to add subscribers but now I want to give unsubscribe link in end of email.

Also it should be without subscriber's login.

Code of create user:

```
$password = wp_generate_password(12, false);
$user_id = wp_create_user($email_address, $password, $email_address);
wp_update_user(
    array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'nickname' => $email_address
    )
);
$user = new WP_User($user_id);
$user->set_role('subscriber');
```

Comment: If you can post here what you have done of enabling he subscription functionality, then probably someone can help you along those lines.

Comment: @zipkundan I have updated question, please review and let me know if you required additional information.